# Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-volume, kubernetes-pvc

This is my postgress config for K8s

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
            name: postgres-storage
```

Following is the event logs

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  35s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/postgres-deployment-d57b94d8-qnk8j to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulling    11s (x3 over 34s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Pulling image "postgres"
  Normal   Pulled     6s (x3 over 30s)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Successfully pulled image "postgres"
  Normal   Created    6s (x3 over 29s)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container postgres
  Warning  Failed     6s (x3 over 29s)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: failed to start container "postgres": Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/DupinderDhiman/.docker/Volumes/database-persistent-volume-claim/pvc-c8155b21-10d9-11ea-b05a-00155d380104': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/DupinderDhiman/.docker: permission denied
```

Yeah, I know you will say, share the drives.
I did 
`docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data`

```
All Users
CatalystOne
Default
Default User
DupinderDhiman
Public
desktop.ini
```

this command runs very well

So the problem is not related to drive sharing

okay next problem may be related to c:/specificFolder permissions. I did I checked all the checkboxes in sharing permission

Now I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending some time, I remember I created one user to share drives for `Docker` with name dockerUser

So the Permission I gave are just for `Administrative user` My own User `DupinderDhiman` but not for `dockerUser`

So Goto C:/user/DupinderDhiman/.docker right click goto properties goto `security tab` 
Click on `Edit` button "To change permission, click Edit" and then click the `Add` button
[image]

now click Advance > then on new dialogue find `Find` button in the bottom you will find one list, find DockerUser > Select it to press okay

[image]

[image]

Okay Okay Okay > apply changes

Close all the open dialogs with okay Apply changes and run the command. See you will not have this error now.